# Error when submitting form: 'Enter a valid date'

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

my views.py:

```
def add_atten(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AttendancenameForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('student:listatten'))
        else:
            print(form.errors)
    else:       
         form = AttendancenameForm()
    return render(request, 'add_atten.html', {'form': form},)
```

my template-add_atten.html:

```
{% if attendance %}
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Teacher</th>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>IN-TIME</th>
            <th>OUT-TIME</th>
        </tr>
    {% for atten in attendance %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{atten.teacher_ name}}</td>
            <td>{{atten.date}}</td>
            <td>{{atten.intime}}</td>
            <td>{{atten.outtime}}</td>
            <td><a href="{% url 'student:updateatten' atten.id   %}">Update</a></td>
        <td><a href="{% url 'student:attendel' atten.pk %}">Delete</a></td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

my models.py:

```
class Attendancename(models.Model):
    teacher_name = models.ForeignKey(Teachername)
    date = models.DateField('Date')
    intime = models.TimeField('IN-TIME')
    outtime = models.TimeField('OUT-TIME')
```

my forms.py:

```
class AttendancenameForm(ModelForm):
    date = forms.DateField(input_formats=['%d-%m-%y'])
    intime = forms.TimeField(input_formats=['%H:%M'])
    outtime = forms.TimeField(input_formats=['%H:%M'])
    teacher_name = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Teachername.objects.all())
    class Meta:
        model = Attendancename
        fields = ('teacher_name', 'date', 'intime', 'outtime',)
```

When I want to submit the value of date it throws error 'enter a valid date'. However I always submit valid values and have tried different combinations, but it doesn't work. Please suggest me the Fix.

Rather than of above if I omitted 'input_formats' from my forms.py and attempt to submit value in my form with default values of date field in django than it doesn't show any error. Please sugggest me a solution.

Comment: It sounds like you're not submitting any data to your form. Perhaps there is an issue with the template and/or the view, you should show these.

Comment: Can we see your view and template?

Comment: I've posted my template and views.py above. My main problem is that form didn't accept values as I specified in input_formats...

Comment: And can you show an example of the date value you are trying to enter?

Comment: The date which I'm entering is - 30-06-2015, 12-12-2014 etc.